# Setting up LangChain for an Interactive Custom Workflow

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I'm interested in setting up a LangChain configuration with a GPT-3.5 language model (LLM) that incorporates custom tools like a circumference calculator and hypotenuse calculator. The objective is to respond appropriately when a user begins an interaction with a question like "I want to calculate the circumference of a circle." The desired response should be "I have the necessary tools to assist you with this calculation. Please provide the radius of the circle." It's important to note that the required parameters for each tool, such as the radius in this case, should not be hard-coded but instead engineered using prompts. Despite researching extensively, I haven't found success so far.

What would be the most effective approach to achieve this? Keep in mind that there could be multiple tools available, and when a specific tool is requested, the LLM should examine the tool to determine the required parameters and prompt the user to input those values if they haven't been provided yet.